# javascript memory management - deleting a complex object

Tags: javascript, memory-management, javascript-objects

I have a big object which holds lot of data. It is structured in this way:

```
myObject = {

   "key1": Array1[256] , // this is array of objects
   "key1": Array2[2048],
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I want to now reset this object ( set it to {} ). Before I do this, I want to de-allocate all the memory. What is the right way of doing it?

If I say delete myObject; would it delete everything? Or do I actually have to delete an array of each key. or even further, Do I have to delete each object in the array of each key as well?

It would be great if you can point me to some good reference material on this topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `delete myObject;`, it will do absolutely nothing, because `delete` removes properties of an object. JavaScript has garbage collection; the way to set this object to `{}` is to just do that:

```
myObject = {};
```

If you want to modify the existing reference (i.e. other things point to the object), you can `delete` each key:

```
for (var k in myObject) {
    delete myObject[k];
}
```

Use strict mode, by the way. It makes things saner, including `delete`.

Comment: This is true, but I would also mention that if the "keyX" properties are being referenced by other portions of the code, they will not be destroyed.

Comment: You can skip the `.hasOwnProperty` check since `delete` will only delete own properties. +1

Comment: @cookiemonster: Ah, thank you! On the other hand, linters… =P

Comment: Similarly if somebody has a reference to the old object, it will not be destroyed.

Comment: what about my last question? would deleting each array delete all the objects in it as well?

Comment: @sublime: An object is garbage-collected when there are no references left to it (that aren’t themselves references from things that will be garbage-collected). So if nothing else refers to those objects, then yes, removing the reference to the array will allow its contents to be collected.

Comment: Then shouldn't by the same logic, all the arrays should be deleted as soon as you say myObject={}. why do I have to delete them each individually?

Comment: @sublime: You don’t have to delete them individually unless something else holds a reference to the object. I didn’t really know what your situation was. Use paragraph 1 if it applies to you.